# Applying a texture to a rotated cylinder

Tags: three.js, 3d

I create a cylinder that I rotate and then update its matrix like so:

```
var cyl = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10, 100, 16, 1, true), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
cyl.rotateZ(THREE.Math.degToRad(-90));
cyl.updateMatrix();
cyl.geometry.applyMatrix(cyl.matrix);
cyl.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
cyl.updateMatrix();
```

However, when I apply a texture to the cylinder, it is drawn rotated to the cylinder surface as if I had not updated the matrix before.

```
var tl = new THREE.TextureLoader();
tl.load(path, function (tex) {
    cyl.material.map = tex;
    cyl.material.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Is there a way I can change this behaviour? Am I maybe missing something when updating the matrix? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV coordinates are tied to vertices. It provides the reference points for the eye dropper pulling color from a texture.

Then its u,v values are interpolated across the face of a triangle between the other vertices it shares the face with.

Moving the vertices around (with a matrix or otherwise) doesn't change that the sampling at all vertices remains the same.

U,V coordinates are also 2d, so there's no reasonable default behavior to expect for rotating them with a 3d matrix transform. Should it rotate UV's based on the rotation along the xy, xz, yz, or an arbitrary axis? Should it rotate them using a pairing of normals and UV mapping, so that upward facing UVs after rotation now get downward facing UVs? It's ambiguous, hence it doesn't happen with a matrix transform.

But if what you really want is to rotate your texture 90 degrees, you have a couple options. You can rotate the image file itself in explorer or finder if you just need 90 degree rotations, you can rotate in photoshop or similar if you need smaller, or you could perform that rotation on the UV values themselves using trigonometry - so you just map current uvs from 0-1 to -1,1 and then rotate using the `new_x = cos(t)x-sin(t)*y; new_y = cos(t)*y+sin(t)*x;` and then remap to 0-1.

If what you just want is for the texture to center on the bottom of the cylinder rather than the side, you can change the THREE.Texture.offset.x/y properties of the texture, but note that the default cylinder UV maps will cause scrunching of the image. You'll need to make your own UV mapping if you don't want distortion on the caps of the cylinder, but that's for another post.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!